# Make a JTextField recieve input even with windows not focused

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm working on a small personal project.

I have two `JFrame` windows, `Viewer` and `Console`.

- `Viewer` only contains a subclass of `JPanel`, and it should respond to mouse input (clicking, mostly).
- `Console` contains a button, a `JTextField` (the input), and a `JTextArea` (the output).

I need to make sure than when I press keys on my keyboard, the corresponding text appears in the Console `JTextField`, not only when the focus is held by the `JTextField`, but also when it's held any other component in my app.

In other words, I want the `JTextField` to accept input even right after I clicked on the `Viewer` frame.

Is this feasible?

In case that matters, I'm running win 8 x64 and I don't really care about portability (I'm the only one that will ever look at or use this code).

EDIT: here is an example of my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



public class main {
    public static Viewer v; 
    public static Console c;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        v=new Viewer();
        c=new Console();
    }


    static class Viewer extends JFrame {
        public Viewer(){
            setSize(600,600);
            getContentPane().add(new myPanel());
            addMouseListener(new mouse());
            setVisible(true);

        }
    }
    static class myPanel extends JPanel{
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(new Color((int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255)));
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
        }
    }
    static class Console extends JFrame {
        public Console(){
            setSize(600,200);
            JTextField text=new JTextField();
            getContentPane().add(text);
            setVisible(true);

        }
    }
    static class mouse implements MouseListener{
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            v.repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }
    }

}
```

In this example, after I click on the big window to change its color, if I want to write stuff in the other window I have to click on it first.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: *"I have two JFrames.."*  That's where the GUI starts to go wrong.  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: Please don't post all of your code. Instead post a shortened, runnable example that reproduces your problem. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I suggest the [KeyboardFocusManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html)? I've found this to be the easiest way to achieve what I believe you are trying to achieve

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(
  new KeyEventDispatcher() {
     public void dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent ke) {
       //TODO: fill this in
     }
  });
```

Comment: This sounds like a promising apporach but I can't figure out how to dispatch the event to the JTextField. Just calling text.dispatchEvent (e) throws a wall of red text. Any suggestions? http://pastebin.com/Uh7xjAw8

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out, I just had to call the redispatchEvent method (duh).
Now it works like a charm, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

One inelegant solution is to create a `KeyListener`, which feeds typed characters to your console, although how exactly this happens depends on how you create your components.  For the sake of this example I'll pretend to do it through a static method in your `Console` class (preferably you'd have access to an instance of `Console`):

```
public class ApplicationKeyListener implements KeyListener {
    public ApplicationKeyListener() {
    }

    // Other necessary methods...

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        char pressed = e.getKeyChar();
        Console.feedChar(pressed);
    }
}
```

And then in `Console`, make sure your `JTextField` object is global and static, then set up the `feedChar()` method.

```
public class Console extends JFrame {
    private static JTextField consoleTextField;

    public Console() {
        consoleTextField = new JTextField();
        // ...
    }

    public static feedChar(char c) {
        consoleTextField.setText(consoleTextField.getText() + c.toString());
    }
}
```

Then finally you'd have to add this listener to all JFrames and their children.

```
public class Viewer extends JFrame {
    public Viewer() {
        ApplicationKeyListener kl = new ApplicationKeyListener();
        addKeyListener(kl);
        for (Component child : this.getComponents()) {
            child.addKeyListener(kl);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work, I would not be able to use backspace, arrow keys and so on

Comment: You could always add on to the listener and check for keycode 8, 37 and 39, etc., then handle them separately by `JTextField.setCaretPosition(int)`, `setText()` and so on .  Of course, if ControlAltDel's answer works, it's about a million times less complicated.